# Visual Studio not validating Office Add-in Manifest

Tags: visual-studio, xsd, office-js

We are attempting to build an add in using functionality in the new VersionOverridesV1_1 section. This works fine on my system (including deploying to Outlook Online from VS), with Visual Studio 2015 and Office Developer Tools 14.0.23025. It is not working on my coworkers system with  VS 2015 and Developer Tools Update 2 (14.0.23928); I've also tried VS 2017 with dev tools 15.0.26112 with the same error.

> The element 'VersionOverrides' in namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides' has
>   invalid child element 'VersionOverrides' in namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1'.
>   List of possible elements expected: 'Description, Requirements, Hosts'
>   in namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides'.

For an example of a manifest that triggers this error, see [this sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send). Create a new Outlook Add in project and paste either manifest in.

It seems that the newer Schemas provided with the newer versions of Office Developer Tools are trying to validate the contents of the first VersionOverrides while not recognizing the 2nd, but it's unclear to me how to properly update these schemas.

Comment: I read some answers on MSDN forums, you should be able to bring new schema on your own, other than waiting for VS update. Unfortunately I didn't pay attention on how to do this as the schemas are pretty simple, not much to validate ;)

Comment: You are correct that the schemas need update.  We have also posted some temporary workarounds in https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send/issues/2.

Answer (score 1):

There's a new workaround at https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send/issues/2. @lgaud, can you try it out, copy/pasted below. Basically, you need to add a dummy Description element, a Requirements element and a Hosts element to the first VersionOverrides section. Sample manifest below:

```
<VersionOverrides xmlns=".../office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">

<!-- workaround starts here -->
<Description resid="residAppDescription" />
<Requirements>
    <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
    </bt:Sets>
</Requirements>
<Hosts>
    <Host xsi:type="MailHost"></Host>
</Hosts>
<!-- workaround ends here -->

<VersionOverrides xmlns=".../office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
    <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
            <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
        </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
            <DesktopFormFactor>
                <!-- Location of the Functions that UI-less buttons can trigger (ExecuteFunction Actions). -->
                <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />
            </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
    </Hosts>
</VersionOverrides>

<Resources>
    <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="residAppDescription" DefaultValue="Foo Description"></bt:String>
    </bt:LongStrings>
</Resources>
```